# Replace systemd-machine-id-setup with alternative?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

We're using a `ubuntu-18.04` template on a virtualization environment. Therefore, before creating the template, we always empty the `/etc/machine-id` file so it's recreated upon the first boot.

The problem is that if several ubuntu-18-based VMs are started at once, `systemd-machine-id-setup` will generate the same ID for all of them, resulting in IP duplication. I checked these servers and they all have the same content in the `/etc/machine-id` file.

[image: IP duplication]

If machines are powered-on spaced in time, different IPs are assigned, thus I assume `systemd-machine-id-setup` is generated based on current time (possibly). This isn't acceptable for us because of the problem in the image above.

Is there a way to make the OS generate the `/etc/machine-id` on boot based on an alternative binary?

**--- UPDATE 1 ---**

On @GeraldSchneider's tip, I [switched back from netplan to ifdownup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces) and the IPs stopped duplicating, so definitely this is a netplan issue.

[image: no duplicated IPs]

Even if this could solve the problem, I'm curious if there's a way to set an alternative way to generate the `/etc/machine-id` file so no duplications happen using netplan.

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/machine-id` to see if it is actually the same on each system? The machine ID file is not normally used to obtain an IP address. How are you assigning IP addresses?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, the `machine-id` file has exactly the same value on the machines that are powered-on within the same time lapse. If machines are powered-on on different time lapses, the file content varies. IP addresses are assigned via DHCP. Actually, this file seems to be used to acquire IP addresses: https://jaylacroix.com/fixing-ubuntu-18-04-virtual-machines-that-fight-over-the-same-ip-address/

Comment: Which versions of ESXi are you running? It might possibly be important.

Comment: It's not VMware, it's oVirt. However, it happens on both infrastructures, so I assume this is an Ubuntu 18 issue, not infrastructure.

Comment: Have you tried if [switching back from netplan to ifupdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031709/ubuntu-18-04-switch-back-to-etc-network-interfaces) makes a difference?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Actually it did a **big** difference. I updated my question with the tests I made.

Comment: You can also switch the netplan DUID back to `MAC` instead of `machine-id` using `dhcp-identifier: mac`, it seems this is a common issue with netplan and the changed DUID.

Comment: @Lenniey this way there are no duplicate IPs either. However, the `/etc/machine-id` is still the same for all machines which is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You can programmatically `rm /etc/machine-id; systemd-machine-id-setup;` via https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-change-the-machine-id/

Comment: @bgStack15 the system itself will call this command if it finds the `/etc/machine-id` empty, which is what I'm doing now. But that exactly what I want to avoid, I want to generate the `machine-id` with a different command upon startup so I make sure it won't generate the same ID for two different machines.

Answer (score 2):

> ...I'm curious if there's a way to set an alternative way to generate the /etc/machine-id file...

Per the [machine-id manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html),

> ...Otherwise, the value in /etc/machine-id will be used. If this file is empty or missing, systemd will attempt to use the D-Bus machine ID from /var/lib/dbus/machine-id, the value of the kernel command line option container_uuid, the KVM DMI product_uuid (on KVM systems), and finally a randomly generated UUID.

And also, towards the bottom of the page,

> The simple configuration file format of /etc/machine-id originates in the /var/lib/dbus/machine-id file introduced by D-Bus. In fact, this latter file might be a symlink to /etc/machine-id.

Therefore, it is also possible to set the machine-id using `dbus-uuidgen`, as can be seen in the following answer:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84793/247886

Per the [dbus-uuidgen manual page](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-uuidgen.1.html),

> If you run dbus-uuidgen with no options it just prints a new uuid made up out of thin air.